# How to get only month & year in SQL QUERY (OPERA)

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

```
select ST.dateOfSale, ST.agreedPrice - C.purchasedPrice AS PROFIT
FROM SalesTransaction ST, Car C
WHERE ST.VIN = C.VIN
GROUP BY (ST.dateOfSale, (ST.agreedPrice - C.purchasedPrice))
ORDER BY ST.dateOfSale DESC ;
```

For each month in 2020, I need to display the total profit generated from car sales only

Please see thje table below:

Car(VIN, dateAcquired, yearBuilt, purchasedPrice, askingPrice)

SalesTransaction(VIN, custID, agentID, dateOfSale, agreedPrice)

Comment: What's wrong your your current query? Post a sample data along with an expected output.

Comment: Current query is giving every single date of each month, rather than every date I want total profit of every month in a MM/YYYY format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good  practice - use JOIN s to join multiple tables

```
SELECT to_char(ST.dateOfSale,'YYYY'),to_char(ST.dateOfSale, 'mm'),SUM( ST.agreedPrice - C.purchasedPrice) AS PROFIT
FROM SalesTransaction ST, Car C
WHERE ST.VIN = C.VIN
GROUP BY to_char(ST.dateOfSale,'YYYY'),to_char(ST.dateOfSale, 'mm');
```

Comment: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments, I got the the error

Comment: what is your database system? which query cause the error? 1 or 2

Comment: its oracle apex

Comment: query is on Mysql. please try edited answer

Comment: Many thanks, just need to see the month name rather than number

Comment: check this https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:1063934100346906822  you can format your month in different ways. If this answer works for you please mark it as answer. this will help others

Comment: thanks, just wondering is there any way to sort out the months in order such as Jan, Feb, March..... its all coming up randomly

Comment: without replacing the 'mm' month get field, add a another month select field for 'JAN..FEB'. sort the query with 'mm' select field and for display use 'JAN..FEB' field. hope you got what I'm trying to say :)